# Fokker-Planck: uniqueness and attractiveness of stationary distribution (gradient systems)

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, stochastic-differential-equations, basins-of-attraction

consider the Langevin equation ($N$-dimensional) with nonlinear drift term but expressible as a gradient of a function $U(\vec{x})$. Namely, consider the stochastic process described by the set of equations:

$\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} U(\vec{x}) + \sqrt{2c} \eta_n$

the problem can be reformulated in terms of the probability distribution $P(\vec{x},t)$, through the following fokker-planck equation:

$\frac{\partial P(\vec{x},t)}{\partial t} = \bigg( - \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \big( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(\vec{x})\big)  + c \sum_{i,j=1}^N \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \bigg) P(\vec{x},t)$

The equation above admits the following stationary solution:

$P^s(\vec{x}) = \mathcal{N} e^{\frac{-U(\vec{x})}{c}}$

Is there a simple way to convince yourself that, in this case, given any initial distribution I always converge only to above $P^s(\vec{x})$?

Comment: I think the Foster-Lyapunov theorem will do the job, under some assumptions about $U$ (which are related to the conditions for your $P^s$ to be normalizable).

Comment: I would expect $d/dt Ent(P(x,t)|P^{s}(x))\le 0$

Comment: Hi @Tobsn , can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: Relative entropy with respect to the stationary distribution decreases along solutions. With additional convexity assumptions on $U$ it will convergege to $0$ exponentially fast.